# how to make a gridview whose items can change index

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make certain grid items disappear. I use the Visibility widget but in the gridview the item does not disappear from the grid list, what should I do?

```
GridView.count(
 shrinkWrap: true,
 crossAxisCount: 2,
 mainAxisSpacing: 7.5,
 crossAxisSpacing: 7.5,
 physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
 children: [
   Visibility(
     visible: false,
     child: Container(
       color: Colors.green,
       child: Center(
         child: Text('1'),
       ),
     ),
   ),

   Visibility(
     visible: true,
     child: Container(
       color: Colors.green,
       child: Center(
         child: Text('2'),
       ),
     ),
   ),

   Visibility(
     visible: true,
     child: Container(
       color: Colors.green,
       child: Center(
         child: Text('3'),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 ],
)
```

what I get
[image: what I get]

what I want

[image: what i want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`Visibility`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html)  is used to show or hide a child.

If you want to remove physical space, use `if` statement

```dart
if (false)
  Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Center(
      child: Text('1'),
    ),
  ),
```

You can also use else state

```dart
if(visible) MyVisibleWidget()
else  MyEmptyWidget(),
```

For `if else` you can also choose `replacement` on `Visibility` widget. I am not using `replacement` in this case because it will eventually add a child in replace of `visible: false,` which is not what we want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know to physically remove it using if, but when I try an error occurs. and it turns out that you don't have to use curly braces like your example